# Redirect stdout/stderr of a background job from console to a log file?

Tags: bash, zsh, sh

I just run a job (assume foo.sh).

```
./foo.sh
[Press Ctrl-Z to stop]
bg  # enter background
```

And it generate output to stdout and stderr.
Is there any method to redirect to stdout and stderr to other file instead of current screen?

Comment: Bring it to FG, redirect the output and send it back to BG.

Comment: @NirAlfasi that doesn't work, at least doing `fg > log.log` doesn't.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apparently I misread your question the first time, so here's my updated answer:

After you sent your program to the background, you first have to find its PID

```
pgrep foo.sh
```

Then you could use `gdb` to attach to that process

```
gdb -p <PID>
```

In `gdb` you then change where this program writes to

```
p dup2(open("/path/to/file",577, 420), 1)
p dup2(1, 2)
```

then you detach from the process and quit `gdb`

```
detach
quit
```

A little explanation

- `577` is equivalent to `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`
- `420` is equivalent to `S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH`
- So the call to `open` opens the file and truncates it to 0 bytes if it exists or creates a new one with the right file permissions if it doesn't exist
- The first call to `dup2` duplicates the file descriptor returned by the call to `open` to file descriptor `1` (which is `stdout`)
- The second call to `dup2` duplicates the file descriptor `1` to `2` (which is `stderr`)

Comment: -1. Does not answer the question that was asked. Specifically, how to redirect output from a *background* job.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, misread the question and corrected this now

Comment: Cool! Downvote retracted.