# Unix alias to redirect background process output

Tags: linux, process, gdb

I'm looking for a way to redirect the output of a background process into `/dev/null` or some other file.

```
$ python ./spam_console.py &
$ [start doing something in the foreground
$ cat test.py
$ [whole console is spammed with output of python program]
```

I'm looking for a way to dump the stdout, stderr of these processes to some file using a simple command line utility.

```
$ dump_to -p 1526 --out /dev/null
```

There is an excellent solution at https://superuser.com/a/732504 using the gdb, but I'm looking for a way to wrap all these behind a simple alias/c program so that it can be used easily on command line. I'm looking for help in accessing gdb in non-interactive (aka programmatic) way to execute the command in the linked article.

Comment: Did you consider to run job with redirect of STDOUT and STDERR? Its much sample and easy

Comment: Yup. I know that i can redirect the output and error using ` >/dev/null 2>&1'. The problem is with the process that you expect the output to be written to a log file but they dump the messages on console (mostly long running java programs).

Comment: Do not expect! just take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after extensive googling of hackernews. [`dupx`](https://www.isi.edu/~yuri/dupx/dupx_man.html) exactly does what I was looking for.

> Dupx is a simple utility to remap files of an already running program. Shells like Bash allow easy input/output/error redirection at the time the program is started using `>`, `<` - like syntax, e.g.:
>
> ```
> echo 'redirect this text' > /tmp/stdout
> ```
>
> will redirect output of echo to `/tmp/stdout`.
>
> Standard shells however do not provide the capability of remapping (redirecting) of output (or input, or error) for an already started process. Dupx tries to address this problem [...]
>
> [...]
>
> Example usage
>
> Note that these examples use bash syntax. First, we start a background bash job that sleeps, then prints something on standard output:
>
> ```
> bash -c 'sleep 1m && echo rise and shine' &
> ```
>
> 1. Redirect the remainder of standard output to `/tmp/stdout`
>
>    The following invocations are equivalent:
>
>    ```
>    dupx -n 0:/tmp/test $!
>    dupx -o /tmp/test $! 
>    dupx $! >>/tmp/test
>    ```
>
>    Note that the last example also remaps stderr and stdin of the process. But because the target process was started on the same tty as `dupx` is being run, they are effectively unchanged.
> 2. Redirect the remainder of stdout, and stderr to different files, read the rest of stdin from `/dev/null`:
>
>    The following invocations are equivalent:
>
>    ```
>    dupx -o /tmp/stdout -e /tmp/stderr -i /dev/null $! 
>    dupx -n 0:/tmp/stdout 1:/dev/null 2:/tmp/stderr $! 
>    dupx >/tmp/stdout 2>/tmp/stderr </dev/null $!
>    ```